# Express Only Serving Static Files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am building an app with React and Express and want the routing to mainly go through Express instead of react-router.

After I built the react app and set Express to serve static files from the build folder, every path leads to only the React app. For example when visiting localhost:3000/test, I still only get the React app instead of "testing."

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   res.send("testing");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely you don't want such results because you want to have your server-side routes exposed to client and route which handle SPA file goes as the last route inside the application. But this code will work for you.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs')
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './client/build')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   const file = fs.createReadStream(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build', 'index.html'));
   return file.pipe(res);
});

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
   res.send("testing");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I hope this will help, happy coding!